# Download file from a redirected website using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to download ZIP file from a website. However it just download the login page in html. Any idea how to download the file from website by entering credential in PowerShell

Below is the procedure to manually download file from browser

**1. Enter URL https://example.com/cms2/fileadmin/reports/test.zip**

**2. It redirect to page to login https://example.com/SSOLogon/manual_login.jsp**

**3. Once I enter the credential, download start automatically**

**Below is the Powershell script which I am using**

```
$filename= 'C:\temp\test.zip'
$url1 = 'https://example.com/SSOLogon/manual_login.jsp'
$url2 = 'https://example.com/cms2/fileadmin/reports/test.zip'

$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url1 -Method Default -SessionVariable foo
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["portal_id"]     = "test@email.com"
$form.Fields["password"] = "password"

Invoke-WebRequest $url2 -WebSession $foo -Body $r
```

Comment: Just making sure I'm not seeing a typo, but it looks like you typed `$foo` after `-SessionVariable`. It shouldn't have the $ in front, it's supposed to be a string, so `-SessionVariable foo`. I'm not sure if you typed the code in and made a typo or not.

Comment: Sorry... It is typo.. Let me edit the code in the question